# Simple Image Segmentation OpenCV-Watershed

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm still pretty new within the image-segmentation / OpenCV scene and hope you can help me out.
Currently, I'm trying to calculate the percentage of the 2 liquids within this photo

[image: Input image]

It should be something like this (as an example)

[image: Expected result]

I thought opencv watershed could help me but I'm unable to get it right. I'm trying to set the markers manually but I get the following error: `(-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC3 && dst.type() == CV_32SC1 in function 'cv::watershed'`
(probably I got my markers all wrong)

If anyone can help me (maybe there is a better way to do this), I would greatly appreciate it

This is the code I use:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image001.jpg')
# convert the image to grayscale and blur it slightly
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

# read image
#img = cv2.imread('jeep.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
hh2 = hh // 2
ww2 = ww // 2

# define circles
radius = hh2
yc = hh2
xc = ww2

# draw filled circle in white on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (xc,yc), radius, (255,255,255), -1)

# apply mask to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, mask)
cv2.imshow("Output", result)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(result,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("ret 1", thresh)

markers = cv2.circle(thresh, (xc,50), 5, 1, -1)
markers = cv2.circle(thresh, (xc,yc+50), 5, 2, -1)
markers = cv2.circle(thresh, (15,15), 5, 3, -1)
cv2.imshow("marker 1", markers)

markers = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
img[markers == -1] = [0,0,255]
cv2.imshow("watershed", markers)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: first step: better picture. something with clear color/brightness differences. no reflections. no shadows. then... chuck all the code. mount the camera so it won't move, make the lighting constant. manually define the circle's position in the picture. manually determine the colors of both areas. use inRange to calculate masks for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you obtain an exception because OpenCV's `watershed()` function [expects `markers` array to be made of 32-bit integers](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1). Converting it forth and back will remove the errors:

```py
markers = markers.astype(np.int32)
markers = cv2.watershed(img, markers)
markers = markers.astype(np.uint8)
```

However, if you execute your code now you will see that the result isn't very good, the watershed algorithm will merge the liquid areas with unwanted regions. To make your code work like this, you should give one marker for every feature in your image. This will be very impractical.

Let's first extract the region of the image which interest us, i.e. the two liquid circle. You already tried to do a masking operation, I improved it in the code below by detecting automatically the circle using OpenCV's [HoughCircles() function](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d). Then the watershed algorithm will need an image with one marker for each region. We will fill the marker image with zeros, place one marker in each liquid area and one marker for the background. Putting all of this together we obtain the code and result below.

Considering the quality of your image (reflects, compression artefacts, etc), I personally think that the result is quite good and I am not sure that another method will give you better than that. On the other side, if you can get better quality images, segmentation methods based on colour space may be more appropriate (as pointed out by [Christoph Rackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192148/simple-image-segmentation-opencv-watershed#comment122300252_69192148)).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image001.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect circle
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.3, 100)

# only one circle is detected
circle = circles[0,0,:]
center_x, center_y, radius = circles[0,0,0], circles[0,0,1], circles[0,0,2]

img_circle = img.copy()
cv2.circle(img_circle, (center_x, center_y), int(radius), (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("circle", img_circle)

# build mask for this circle
mask = np.zeros(img_gray.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask, (center_x, center_y), int(radius), 255, -1)

img_masked = img.copy()
img_masked[mask == 0] = 0
cv2.imshow("image-masked", img_masked)

# create markers
markers = np.zeros(img_gray.shape, np.int32)
markers[10, 10] = 1                                        # background marker
markers[int(center_y - radius*0.9), int(center_x)] = 100   # top liquid
markers[int(center_y + radius*0.9), int(center_x)] = 200   # bottom liquid

# do watershed
markers = cv2.watershed(img_masked, markers)
cv2.imshow("watershed", markers.astype(np.uint8))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Watershed segmentation result]
[image: Segmentation result on original image]

Comment: Thank you @vvanpelt! This really made my day.

I needed to adjust the cv2.circle to use roundings but other than that it works flawlessly:

cv2.circle(mask, (int(round(center_x)), int(round(center_y))), int(radius), 255, -1)

Comment: Nice to know @CodeViper ! Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.